# Is there any advantage when using magnetic stirring vs the common grinding?

Tags: experimental-physics

Is there any advantage when using magnetic stirring vs the common grinding?? In terms of the shearing forces applied on over the sample and its degradation

Comment: I don't know what magnetic stirring means, but I don't think it has anything to do with particle physics. Can you clarify what the context of the question is?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with particle physics. The context is as follows: I have a solid sample and I need to spin coat it over a glass substrate. So I need either to grind it and dissolve it or to use a magnetic stirrer and heat already with the solvent that I was gonna use. Does the grinding cause more damage to the micro/nano structure of my sample than the magnetic stirrer with heat? I could see on SEM images that the grinding already cause a lot of damage over these structures ........

Comment: .....So the question is if the magnetic stirring of the sample is more gentle than the flattening of the sample by grinding? I'll post link to magnetic stirring

Comment: https://www.pce-instruments.com/english/laboratory-technology/laboratory/magnetic-stirrer-kat_159371.htm